# Counting current items by month

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to build a monthly tally of active equipment, grouped by service area from a database log table. I think I'm 90% of the way there; I have a list of months, along with the total number of items that existed, and grouped by region.

However, I also need to know the state of each item as they were on the first of each month, and this is the part I'm stuck on. For instance, Item 1 is in region A in January, but moves to Region B in February. Item 2 is marked as 'inactive' in February, so shouldn't be counted. My existing query will always count item 1 in region A, and item 2 as 'active'.

I can correctly show that Item 3 is deleted in March, and Item 4 doesn't show up until the April count. I realize that I'm getting the first values because my query is specifying the min date, I'm just not sure how I need to change it to get what I want.

I think I'm looking for a way to group by Max(OperationDate) for each Month.

The Table looks like this:

```
| EQUIPID | EQUIPNAME | EQUIPACTIVE | DISTRICT | REGION |        OPERATIONDATE | OPERATION |
|---------|-----------|-------------|----------|--------|----------------------|-----------|
|       1 |    Item 1 |           1 |        1 |      A | 2015-01-01T00:00:00Z |       INS |
|       2 |    Item 2 |           1 |        1 |      A | 2015-01-01T00:00:00Z |       INS |
|       3 |    Item 3 |           1 |        1 |      A | 2015-01-01T00:00:00Z |       INS |
|       2 |    Item 2 |           0 |        1 |      A | 2015-02-10T00:00:00Z |       UPD |
|       1 |    Item 1 |           1 |        1 |      B | 2015-02-15T00:00:00Z |       UPD |
|       3 |    (null) |      (null) |   (null) | (null) | 2015-02-21T00:00:00Z |       DEL |
|       1 |    Item 1 |           1 |        1 |      A | 2015-03-01T00:00:00Z |       UPD |
|       4 |    Item 4 |           1 |        1 |      B | 2015-03-10T00:00:00Z |       INS |
```

There is also a subtable that holds attributes that I care about. It's structure is similar. Unfortunately, due to previous design decisions, there is no correlation to operations between the two tables. Any joins will need to be done using the EquipmentID, and have the overlapping states matched up for each date.

Current query:

```
--cte to build date list
 WITH calendar (dt) AS
 (SELECT &fromdate from dual
      UNION ALL
    SELECT Add_Months(dt,1)
    FROM calendar
    WHERE dt < &todate)
 
SELECT dt, a.district, a.region, count(*)
FROM
  (SELECT EQUIPID, DISTRICT, REGION, OPERATION, MIN(OPERATIONDATE ) AS FirstOp, deleted.deldate
    FROM Equipment_Log
    LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT EQUIPID,MAX(OPERATIONDATE) as DelDate
        FROM Equipment_Log
        WHERE OPERATION = 'DEL'
        GROUP BY EQUIPID
      ) Deleted
    ON  Equipment_Log.EQUIPID = Deleted.EQUIPID
    WHERE OPERATION <> 'DEL' --AND additional unimportant filters
    GROUP BY EQUIPID,DISTRICT, REGION , OPERATION, deldate
  ) a
  INNER JOIN calendar
  ON  (calendar.dt >= FirstOp AND calendar.dt < deldate) 
    OR (calendar.dt >= FirstOp AND deldate is null)
  LEFT JOIN 
      ( SELECT EQUIPID, MAX(OPERATIONDATE) as latestop
      FROM SpecialEquip_Table_Log
      --where SpecialEquip filters
      group by EQUIPID
      ) SpecialEquip
    ON a.EQUIPID = SpecialEquip.EQUIPID and calendar.dt >= SpecialEquip.latestop
    
GROUP BY dt, district, region
ORDER BY dt, district, region
```

Comment: If item appears in Jan,is deleted in March, but there is no entry for that item in Feb should it appear in Feb?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Looking forward to checking out the answer you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Take only last operation for each id. This is what row_number() and `where rn = 1` do.

We have calendar and data. Make [partitioned join](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=312).

I assumed that you need to fill values for months where entries for id are missing. So `nvl(lag() ignore nulls)` are needed, because if something appeared in January it still exists in Feb, March and we need district, region values from last not empty row.

Now you have everything to make count. That part where you mentioned `SpecialEquip_Table_Log` is up to you, because you left-joined this table and not used it later, so what is it for? Join if you need it, you have id.

**<sup>[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9416b807c08658b7ecaa4e86f78540b5)</sup>**

```
with 
  calendar(mth) as (
    select date '2015-01-01' from dual union all
    select add_months(mth, 1) from calendar where mth < date '2015-05-01'),
  data as (
    select id, dis, reg, dt, op, act
      from (
        select equipid id, district dis, region reg,
               to_char(operationdate, 'yyyy-mm') dt, 
               row_number() 
                   over (partition by equipid, trunc(operationdate, 'month') 
                   order by operationdate desc) rn, 
               operation op, nvl(equipactive, 0) act
          from t)
      where rn = 1 )
select mth, dis, reg, sum(act) cnt
  from (
    select id, mth, 
           nvl(dis, lag(dis) ignore nulls over (partition by id order by mth)) dis, 
           nvl(reg, lag(reg) ignore nulls over (partition by id order by mth)) reg,
           nvl(act, lag(act) ignore nulls over (partition by id order by mth)) act
      from calendar
      left join data partition by (id) on dt = to_char(mth, 'yyyy-mm') )
  group by mth, dis, reg
  having sum(act) > 0
  order by mth, dis, reg
```

It may seem complicated, so please run subqueries separately at first to see what is going on. And test :) Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for setting up the DB Fiddle, that was above and beyond. I made a small update here: [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=553c4ca18828001e15a191a9350d0cf9) If the first 3 items are added in 2012, they won't show up in January 2015 using your example.

Comment: If report is made for 2015 then data from 2012 is not analysed. To include such data we would have to do initial state for everything before 2015 and treat it as first operation of 2015-01, make union at first.